# How to slice a list based on boolean indices

Tags: python

For example:

```
listA = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
listB = [True, False, True, False]
```

How to extract the elements in `listA` with `True`, something like `listA(listB)`, to obtain `["a", "c"]`? It is better to have a one-line code to achieve so.

Comment: Please add an expected output

Comment: `[a for i,a in enumerate(listA) if listB[i]]`

Comment: @PatrickArtner Why would you use `enumerate` for this when `zip` exists?

Comment: `[a for a,b in zip(listA,listB) if b]` lots of ways to get where you want :) @khelwood - you are correct, this is even better

Comment: Actually, there is [`compress()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress) in *itertools* which do exactly what you want. `list(compress(listA, listB))`

Comment: @OlvinRoght Thanks! It is a neat solution

Comment: I occassionally use itertools, but zip is probably the most pythonic "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it" solution

Answer (score 0):

```
ListA = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
ListB = [True, False, True, False]
ListC = []
for X in range(len(ListA)):
    if ListB[X] == True:
        ListC.append(ListA[X])
print(ListC)
```

This loops through list A and appends to list C if list B is true